# implicit type conversion in C++ using overloaded =

Tags: c++, type-conversion

in the below code (which is an example for type conversion):

```
// implicit conversion of classes:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B {
public:
  // conversion from A (constructor):
  B (const A& x) {}
  // conversion from A (assignment):
  B& operator= (const A& x) {return *this;}
  // conversion to A (type-cast operator)
  operator A() {return A();}
};

int main ()
{
  A foo;
  B bar = foo;    // calls constructor
  bar = foo;      // calls assignment
  foo = bar;      // calls type-cast operator
  return 0;
}
```

in line 21:
`bar = foo;      // calls assignment` 
it calls the overloaded operator =. and in the body of class overloading for "=" operator is written in line 12:
`B& operator= (const A& x) {return *this;}`
it's statement says "return this". here this points to bar. and there's just a parameter of type class A:
`const A& x`
what does this function do with this parameter?
and in line 21 what is converted to what by writing:
`bar = foo;` ?

Comment: "what does this function do with this parameter?" nothing, The parameter is unused

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: There's nothing for it to do, as neither `A` nor `B` have any data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Assignment operators don't convert anything, they copy things from one object to another but both objects already exist.

Comment: _"...what does this function do with this parameter?..."_ - nothing it's just skeleton code (as `class A` is empty and also `class B` contains no members).  Usually you would write some code to do the assignment in a meaningful fashion copying member of `A` to `B` or even something else.

Comment: There's not much special about an assignment operator, it's convention that makes you use them for assignment. The normal rules for functions also apply to any assignment operator you write, so try to understand the code above by thinking about the assignment operator as a regular function.

Comment: Just a remark, but specially in larger projects implicit conversions can be very tricky. They can be chained together and lead to unpredictable conversions. So in all code reviews I do, remove implicit type conversion opertains and make all constructors with one parameter explicit. The little pain now of typing explicit conversions where you want them may safe you a lot of pain later.

Comment: Since both classes are empty none of the code does anything at all. It's all just hot air.

Answer (score 2):

The real question you might be asking is what does the operator= function used for?

Normally we take some data from the constant reference
For example

```
struct A{
    std::string data;
}

struct B{
    std::string differentData;

    B& operator=(const A& other){
        differentData = other.data;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Then if we call code like

```
int main(){
    A a;
    a.data = "hello";
    B b;
    b = a;

    std::cout << b.differentData;
}
```

We should get "hello" printing to the console

Since you're not interacting with the class given in the function, all this code is doing is running an empty function.

The return is only used if you chain together equal calls

```
int main(){
    B b1, b2, b3;

    b3.differentData = "hi";
    b1 = b2 = b3;
    //Pushes hi from b3 >> b2 and returns b2
    //Pushes hi from b2 >> b1 and returns b1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what does this function do with this parameter?

Nothing.

> what is converted to what by writing: `bar = foo;`

Nothing. Or equivalently, the state of `bar` is replaced from the state of `foo`.